# how to pass reference to existing VPC to a cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am creating a cloudformation template, with few resources, couple of lambda functions , S3 bucket.see code below, it is work on progress and so far I have a S3 bucket and a lamda function triggered by S3. we have vpc defined in our team that we are supposed to use. I would like to add private subnet under that vpc for my lambda function and assign public subnet for the s3 bucket. how to get reference of the vpc , and pass it to my template and use it? sample code will be helpful.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:

  # S3 Bucket
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  # Functions
  S3-Lambda-trigger:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Description: s3 object creation triggers lambda
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        S3Bucket:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'

  # Permissions
  Allow-lamda-invocation-s3:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref S3-Lambda-trigger
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get reference of the vpc , and pass it to my template and use it?

One way would be through [AWS-Specific Parameter Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types), specifically `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id`, in a `Parameters` section.

For example:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters: 

  VPCId: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

Resources:

  MySubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties: 
      # other properties
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
```

Thanks to this, when creating the stack in AWS Console, you would be able to choose **existing VPCId** to pass to the template.

Comment: thanks. one thing comes to mind, I am setting this up in my dev environment currently and plan to use the same template later in prod. to use the same template, the vpc id would need to be same in both environments?

Comment: @ozil No problem. The VPCId would be chosen when you deploy your template. Thus you can use same or different VPC at that time. You can also specify a `Default` value for the parameter, if the VPCId would be same for both dev and prod. Hope this helps?